# how to convert current screen to landscape mode in phoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, landscape

We are developing  phone-gap application.We have 4 pages like one.html,two.html,three.html,four.html.In this one(two.html) of the HTML file need to be landscape mode automatically.

Please guide to us.We are new to this.

Answer (score 1):

Add this script first

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then inside another script tag

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var so = cordova.plugins.screenorientation;
        so.setOrientation(so.Orientation.LANDSCAPE);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Screen Orientation PhoneGap Plugin for Android

Following is the link.

https://github.com/their/pg-plugin-screen-orientation

Comment: we tried as in link but we don't have luck Please tell me Where it's Placed navigator.screenOrientation.set('landscape');